# Textinput keyboard closes after every Keypress in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native app. it renders initially it render a timeslot(consist of two TextInput components) under every day of week(eg: monday). it has ability to remove or add a timeslot.

I am using useState to keep track of the number of timeslot rendered using a 2d array.

Every time i use a textInput the keyboard automatically dismisses.

please help me regarding the issue.

```
 const [inputState, _updateInputState] = useState({});
  const [inputCompList, updateInputCompList] = useState({
    Monday: [[1, 2]],
    Tuesday: [[1, 2]],
    Thursday: [[1, 2]],
    Friday: [[1, 2]],
  });

  const updateInputState = (val, name) => {
    _updateInputState({...inputState, [name]: val});
  };
  console.log(inputState);
  const InputComp = ({inputName}) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.textInput, page2Styles.inputContainer]}>
        {!inputState[inputName] && (
          <Text style={[styles.text, page2Styles.placeholder]}>5:20</Text>
        )}
        <TextInput
          value={inputState[inputName]}
          onChangeText={text => updateInputState(text, inputName)}
          style={page2Styles.txtInpt}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Dates available</Text>
      <View>
        {Object.keys(inputCompList).map(key => (
          <View key={key}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{key}</Text>
            {inputCompList[key].map((arr, i) => (
              <View style={page2Styles.inputContainer} key={i}>
                {arr.map((val, j) => (
                  <InputComp key={key + i + j} inputName={key + i + j} />
                ))}
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try KeyboardAvoidingView? You can read documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)